# Adding nic to virtual machine via kvm not showing up inside machine

Tags: networking, centos, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to add a new nic (eth1) to a virtual machine that I have set up using virt-manager. I can use Virt-manager to add the hardware but when the machine is booted no new cards show up. What have I missed?

Extra info:

As it stands the virtual machine only has one card on it. It is Host device eth0 (Bridge 'br0') which is seen by the virtual machine and the device model is virtio.

Comment: post the VM's domxml after you've added the second card, and the relevant additional info on the host and guest (ifconfig -a, brctl show etc)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to kvm in general. When I try to run 

`virsh dumpxml VMNAME > domxml.xml`  

I get this back.  

`'error: failed to get domain 'DOMAIN'`

`error: Domain not found: no domain with matching name 'DOMAIN'`

Comment: You have to completely shut down the VM (not just reboot) for this change to take effect.

Comment: virsh, virt-manager and other tools aren't KVM, they are libvirt tools. If you create and start a VM via libvirt tools, libvirt should be able to track the VM, e.g. `virsh list` should be able to show the VM's status and virsh dumpxml should produce the domxml. Of course, some distros have it completely broken and you might be hitting a bug.